# Mono for Android: Unicode Assets file names can't be packaged

Tags: android, unicode, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

When an asset contains unicode characters in the file name, for example Chinese or Arabic, the file can not be deployed to a package, it errors out.

Renaming the file to ANSI characters fixes it.

Is there a way to get MonoDevelop + MonoDroid deploy unicode Assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this from the MonoDroid team (thanks jonp) and it works:

Since Android doesn't support Unicode asset filenames, you can instead set the
file's Build action to EmbeddedResource and use .NET resources to access the
resource:

```
  using (var s = new StreamReader (typeof (Activity1).Assembly
       .GetManifestResourceStream ("Úñîćödę.txt")))
   button.Text = s.ReadToEnd ();
```

(You may need to change the Resource ID property of the file to match the value
passed to Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream().)

Answer (score 6):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but asset filenames *must* be ASCII, because that's what the [`aapt` tool requires](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#L27):

```cpp
/*
 * Names of asset files must meet the following criteria:
 *
 *  - the filename length must be less than kMaxAssetFileName bytes long
 *    (and can't be empty)
 *  - all characters must be 7-bit printable ASCII
 *  - none of { '/' '\\' ':' }
 *
 * Pass in just the filename, not the full path.
 */
static bool validateFileName(const char* fileName)
{
    const char* cp = fileName;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (*cp != '\0') {
        if ((*cp & 0x80) != 0)
            return false;           // reject high ASCII
        if (*cp < 0x20 || *cp >= 0x7f)
            return false;           // reject control chars and 0x7f
        if (strchr(kInvalidChars, *cp) != NULL)
            return false;           // reject path sep chars
        cp++;
        len++;
    }

    if (len < 1 || len > kMaxAssetFileName)
        return false;               // reject empty or too long

    return true;
}
```

I have no idea why Android/`aapt` has this requirement.

Comment: Requirement is because aapt generates the R file that has a field/variable with the name of each file you put in the assets (and even raw) folder. Since java variable names can't have unicode, it can't package files with them as it would generate an invalid Java class.

Comment: Java variables names most certainly _can_ have Unicode: [§3.8 Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says "Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set, which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today, including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are written in their native languages."