# Is it possible to use korean characters as file name in android

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I'am writing simple app to learn korean sylabs for android os.
Is it possible to use korean characters as file name in android os?
When I'am trying to get file from assets dir i get this exception:

> 07-21 19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   가.mp3 07-21 19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method) 07-21
>   19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:331) 07-21
>   19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   net.garagefarm.hangulteatcher.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:141)
>   07-21 19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222) 07-21 19:33:39.558:
>   W/System.err(7315):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273) 07-21
>   19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 07-21
>   19:33:39.558: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 07-21
>   19:33:39.566: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-21 19:33:39.566:
>   W/System.err(7315):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895) 07-21
>   19:33:39.566: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-21
>   19:33:39.566: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-21 19:33:39.566:
>   W/System.err(7315):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
>   07-21 19:33:39.566: W/System.err(7315):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761) 07-21
>   19:33:39.566: W/System.err(7315):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-21 19:38:39.495:
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7315): getSelectedText on inactive
>   InputConnection 07-21 19:38:39.495: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7315):
>   setComposingText on inactive InputConnection

What is interesting when i changed file name to "1.mp3" everything works fine.

Here is code to load file:

```
            num.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         if (player.isPlaying()) {
                             player.stop();
                         }

                        player.release();
                        player = new MediaPlayer();

                        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                        AssetManager manager = parent.getAssets();
                        try {
                            FileInputStream mp3Stream = 
                                manager.openFd(tv.getText() + ".mp3").createInputStream();
                            player.setDataSource(
                                mp3Stream.getFD());

                            player.prepare();
                            player.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        matrixSelected(tv);
                    }
                });
```

from debugger:
mText   "가" (id=830041403152)

file name is still:
가.mp3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543713/mono-for-android-unicode-assets-file-names-cant-be-packaged

Comment: thanks for replay but this is about how to solve problem in mono enviroment. It is partial answer. As i see in java, resource have to be named with ASCII encoding to be avaiable in R.*, but is there any way to access this file via inputstream with given filaname?

Comment: No, as the linked question explains, `aapt`, the Android packaging tool that creates your APK, does not support Unicode asset filenames.  Android itself supports Unicode names for actual files, but your asset isn't being packaged correctly on your development machine.